# Converting .nrrd Segmentation to Nifti Volume with reference volume

Tags: python, data-conversion, dataformat, nifti, medical-imaging

I have 200+ CT-Volume Files with matching segmentations. The Volumes are in .nrrd format and the segmentations are in seg.nrrd format. I need both of those as .nii.gz format and I want to script the conversion from one into the other format.

Regarding the Volumes, everything has been quite easy, using sitk:

import SimpleITK as sitk

img = sitk.ReadImage(“your_image.nrrd”)
sitk.WriteImage(img, “your_image.nii.gz”)

I just did the same thing with the segmenations, too, which worked fine at first glance. But the problem is now that the segmentations are not registered with the Volumes anymore. The image dimensions as well as image origins are not the same anymore and thus, I cannot process the converted images.

The same happens, when I do the following manual steps with 3D-Slicer : 1. Load the .seg.nrrd files into Slicer as Segementation 2. Save the segmentation as .nrrd file instead of seg.nrrd 3. Import the .nrrd file as Volume and save the segmentation as .nii.gz

But I figured out a way to convert the data types manually while keeping all dimensions: 1. Import the Volume as well as the corresponding segmentation (.seg.nrrd) 2. Export the segmentation to a labelmap with reference volume set to my corresponding volume 3. Save the Labelmap as nii.gz (4. Not sure if I need that step for my project: Convert Labelmap to Scalar Volume and safe as nii.gz)

In both cases 3. and 4. I have a nii.gz file with matching dimensions. But since I have 200+ Volumes, I need to script that. But I haven’t found anything so far. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [`Resample`](https://torchio.readthedocs.io/transforms/preprocessing.html#resample) transform in [TorchIO](https://torchio.readthedocs.io/) for that:

```py
import torchio as tio

# Fill these two lists
ct_paths = []
seg_paths = []

for ct_path, seg_path in zip(ct_paths, seg_paths):
    image = tio.LabelMap(seg_path)
    transform = tio.Resample(ct_path)
    transformed = transform(image)
    out_path = seg_path.replace('.seg', '_registered')
    transformed.save(out_path)
```

If your pairs have the same spacing and directions, this will simply pad your segmentations so the origins and shapes are coherent.

Disclaimer: I am the main developer of TorchIO.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to convert the label.nrrd with a refernce image, such as a CT or MRI image with FTITI or nrrd format. The key word is to use a SimpleITK function, TransformPhysicalPointToIndex, to convert the origin of the label.nrrd to the related index in the image space. Hope the following demo may help you

```
roi_data = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(roi_image)
start_point = ref_image.TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(roi_image.GetOrigin())
  
new_roi_array = np.zeros(ref_image.GetSize())
new_roi_array[start_point[0]: start_point[0] + roi_image.GetSize()[0], 
              start_point[1]: start_point[1] + roi_image.GetSize()[1], 
              start_point[2]: start_point[2] + roi_image.GetSize()[2]
              ] = roi_data
  
new_roi_image = sitk.GetImageFromArray(new_roi_array)
new_roi_image.CopyInformation(ref_image)
```